# How do I check if a string is a palindrome using recursion, without reversing or using a duplicate array

Tags: arrays, c, recursion, palindrome

The conditions are:(these are part of the question, so I cannot bypass them)

1. **I cannot reverse the array**, so the strrev function, or writing a reverse function is pointless.
2. **I cannot use another array**, to copy the alphabets into it
3. There are whitespaces and commas, etc in the string and I have to disregard those while checking, but **I am not allowed to remove those from the string**

Literally the approach I had in my mind melted away after reading this,
and yes I HAVE to **use recursion** for this.

I just thought writing a function:
int palindrome(char arr[], int length) that returns a flag=0/1
should do the trick but I'm having trouble figuring out how to check beginning and end characters without removing the whitespace or commas.
Any ideas or hints towards a possible solution to this madness?

it should work for stuff like:

1. noon.
2. Sit on a potato pan, Otis

Comment: "find the palindrome of a string" you mean *check if a string is a palindrome*.

Comment: `I'm having trouble figuring out how to check beginning and end characters without removing the whitespace or commas` what problem do you have to just bypass them ?

Comment: `int palindrome(char arr[], int first, int last)` where `first` and `last` are indexes into the array. The initial call should be `palindrome(str, 0, strlen(str) - 1)`

Comment: to have to use recursion to check a string is a palindrome is clearly a non sense ... Anyway what did you try by yourself ?

Comment: @user3386109 yes, this is along the lines of what i was thinking, but  how do i increment and decrement first and last respectively? because I might have a character in the third character from the beginning but a space or a comma from the end?

Comment: Recursion: a string is a palindrome if the two ends are equal **and** if the inner smaller string is a palindrome ... an empty string or a string of length 1 is a palindrome

Comment: @pmg yes I understand that, but how do I identify the ends if the sentence is irregular with whitespace and commas? like the second example I have given above.

Comment: in the same way you bypass whitespace and comma from the beginning you bypass them from teh end

Comment: @bruno i'm not bypassing it anywhere- i cannot figure out the logic in this scenario

Comment: you have to bypass, just add / remove 1 to the index / pointer of the current begini / end, that is all, and in the same way you progress for other chars

Comment: `palindrome(arr, first+1, last)` skips a character at the beginning. `palindrome(arr, first, last-1)` skips a character at the end. `palindrome(arr, first+1, last-1)` removes a matching pair.

Answer (score 3):

```
int palindrome(char arr[], int length);
```

With this signature, you can throw away characters from the beginning and end of the string, without changing the string itself:

- To throw away the first character, increase the pointer:

  `palindrome(arr + 1, length - 1);`
- To throw away the last character, decrease the length:

  `palindrome(arr, length - 1);`

Now think about a recursive definition of a palindrome; something like this:

- If the first or last character is not a letter, throw it away and check whether the rest is a palindrome
- If the first and last character are letters, compare them

  - Equal? Throw them away and check whether the substring is a palindrome
  - Not equal? Not a palindrome

You have to implement the logic carefully; this is only a general idea.

Comment: Suggestion: `int palindrome(char const *arr, int length);`

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass the string size along with its address, as in

```
        int palindrome(char arr[], int length)`
```

Something like this will work:

```
int isPal_r(const char* str, const size_t size)
{
    if (size < 2) return 1;  // trivial
    if (*str != *(str + size - 1))
        return 0;                       // not palindrome
    return isPal_r(str + 1, size - 2);  // try inner string
}
```

- we have no secondary arrays
- the array is not reversed

But there is `3.` about ignoring commas and white space. And as the 2nd example shows, you must also ignore case:

```
Sit on a potato pan, Otis
```

should be a valid palindrome.

#### A way to go

These 3 functions

```
char is_valid(const char ch)
{
    if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')) return ch - 0x20;
    if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z')) return ch;
    return -1;
}

char* last_valid(char* p)
{
    char* last = p;
    while (*p != 0)
    {
        char ch = is_valid(*p);
        if (ch > 0) last = p;
        ++p;
    }
    return last;
}

char* next_valid(char* p)
{
    while (is_valid(*p) < 0) ++p;
    return p;
}
```

- `is_valid()` can be used to determine if a letter is valid so we can skip values based on a table.
- `last_valid()` and `next_valid()` can be used to adjust the string pointers.

By using the 1st to compute string size and the others to navigate we can use the same code:

```
int isPal_r(char* str, const size_t size)
{
    if (size < 2) return 1;  // trivial
    char* first = next_valid(str);
    char* last  = last_valid(str);
    char  ch1   = *first;
    char  ch2   = *last;
    ch1 = ((ch1 >= 'a') && (ch1 <= 'z')) ? 'A' + ch1 - 'a'
                                         : ch1;
    ch2 = ((ch2 >= 'a') && (ch2 <= 'z')) ? 'A' + ch2 - 'a'
                                         : ch2;
    if (ch1 != ch2) return -1;
    *last = 0;
    return isPal_r( next_valid(first+1), size - 2);  // try inner string
}
```

#### a test program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int   isPal(char*);
void  test_isPal(char*);
char  is_valid(const char);
char* next_valid(char*);
char* last_valid(char*);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "\nPlease enter strings on the command line: "
            "Usage: program "
            "str1 str2 ...\n");
        return -1;
    }
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "     %d arguments.\n     Return 1 for a "
        "palindrome, or 0\n\n",
        argc - 1);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < argc; i += 1)
        test_isPal(argv[i]);
    return 0;
}

int isPal_r(char* str, const size_t size)
{
    if (size < 2) return 1;  // trivial
    char* first = next_valid(str);
    char* last  = last_valid(str);
    char  ch1   = *first;
    char  ch2   = *last;
    ch1 = ((ch1 >= 'a') && (ch1 <= 'z')) ? 'A' + ch1 - 'a'
                                         : ch1;
    ch2 = ((ch2 >= 'a') && (ch2 <= 'z')) ? 'A' + ch2 - 'a'
                                         : ch2;
    if (ch1 != ch2) return -1;
    *last = 0;
    return isPal_r( next_valid(first+1), size - 2);  // try inner string
}

void test_isPal(char* str)
{
    if (str == NULL) return;
    fprintf(stderr, "\nstring is \"%s\"\n", str);
    char*  p    = (char*)str;
    size_t size = 0;
    while (*p != 0)
    {
        if (is_valid(*p) > 0) ++size;  // strlen
        ++p;
    }
    int res = isPal_r((char*) str, size);
    fprintf(stderr, "     isPal_r() returned %d\n", res);
}

char is_valid(const char ch)
{
    if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')) return ch - 0x20;
    if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z')) return ch;
    return -1;
}

char* last_valid(char* p)
{
    char* last = p;
    while (*p != 0)
    {
        char ch = is_valid(*p);
        if (ch > 0) last = p;
        ++p;
    }
    return last;
}

char* next_valid(char* p)
{
    while (is_valid(*p) < 0) ++p;
    return p;
}
```

#### output for some tests

```
SO >
SO > v1 noon "Sit on a potto pan, Otis" X 121 223322 abcdxba
     6 arguments.
     Return 1 for a palindrome, or 0


string is "noon"
     isPal_r() returned 1

string is "Sit on a potto pan, Otis"
     isPal_r() returned 1

string is "X"
     isPal_r() returned 1

string is "121"
     isPal_r() returned 1

string is "223322"
     isPal_r() returned 1

string is "abcdxba"
     isPal_r() returned -1

SO > v1

Please enter strings on the command line: Usage: program str1 str2 ...

SO >
```